# Docusign e signature - allow my website users send signature request

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to integrate Docusign to my web application. The workflow is as follows:

1. User Bob visits my website and sign in
2. Bob uploads a document to be sent to his friend Alice, who then should sign the document
3. After Alice signs the document, Bob is notified (via email, etc.)

Is this workflow at all possible?

Does Bob have to have a Docusign account?
Or can I (web application) send esignature request on behalf of Bob?

EDIT/UPDATE
Does Bob have to authenticate via docusign on my website? If so, is Bob charged for this or our docusign dev account?
Can out website send the document to Alice on behalf of Bob?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your flow is as below

- User Bob visits my website and signs in
- Bob uploads a document to be sent to his friend Alice
- Bob will sign first, then the document goes to Alice
- who then should sign the document
- After Alice signs the document

In the above case, Bob and Alice will both will be signers so they will be notified once the document is in a `completed` state (both have signed.)

User can configure their own email notification settings manually via the DocuSign web UI, see: https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-manage-notifications.

OR

If you don't wish to change your flow,

Then configure the `webhook`

then once Alice signs the document, it will be in a completed state.
webhook will be triggered.
then can trigger emails from your application.
Have a look at the [webhook document here.](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/webhooks/)

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks! 
Does Bob have to authenticate via docusign on my website? If so, is Bob charged for this or our docusign dev account? Can out website send the document to Alice on behalf of Bob?

Comment: all documents will be sent on behalf of your dev account. Bob doesn't need to authenticate.

Comment: @AmolMohite Is it possible to use Bob's account for him? Do we have the dev account and Bob's account and Bob's account is the one that is charged instead of the dev account. We are just acting on his behalf and don't think we should pay for all his documents. Thanks.